# boostrapvalidator textarea validation always green

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator

I am having this textarea code:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
<textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="Op_Question" name="Op_Question" rows="2" data-bv-field="Op_Question"></textarea>
</div>
```

and i am having this code for bootstrapvalidator:

```
            Op_Question: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Question is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 500,
                        message: 'Post content must be less than 120 characters'
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem is that, bootstrap validator is always green, even when the textarea is empty, why does that happens according to you ?

Cheers